# Change Label Color if validation fails

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML which has a `label` and `input` field like this:

```
<div class="table-cell segmented">
    <label for="email" class="field-label">email</label>
    <input id="email" name="email" class="required" type="email" placeholder="Required"  />
    <input type="hidden" id="forgotPasswordInput" name="forgotPasswordInput" value="false"/>
</div>`
```

I want to change the color of the `label` with the `id` of "name" when the `input`-validation fails. I don't need to change the color of the label that is added after the `input` if the validation fails.

I have the below method to validate:

```
var validator =$("#loginForm").validate({ 
            rules: { 
                email: {
                    required:true,
                    email:true,
                    emailRule: true,
                },
                emailPass: {
                    required:true,          
                },
            }, 
            messages: { 
                email: {
                    required:"enter email",
                    email:"invalid email",
                },
                emailPass:{
                    required:"enter password",
                },
            }       
        });
```

Comment: You have no label with the id "name" And you should format your javascript

Comment: I modified my question to what I need

Comment: You may have modified it to what *you* need, but without the relevant elements that *you* want to us to help you style, it's nearly impossible to answer. So, please: consider helping us out. If only because that way *we* can help *you*. Which is, surely, the point of asking the question, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use the invalidHandler method.

```
var validator =$("#loginForm").validate({
  rules: {
    email: { required:true, email:true, emailRule: true, },
    emailPass: { required:true,}
  },
  messages: {
    email: { required:"enter email", email:"invalid email", },
    emailPass:{ required:"enter password", }
  },
  invalidHandler: function (ev, validator) {
    $('select your label').css('color', 'the new color');
  }
});
```

Comment: By the way, here is a link to the jquery validator [docs page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.row').find('label[for=name]').css({"color": "red"});
```

Comment: I am trying to do the same as given in my code below

var validator =$("#loginForm").validate({ 
   rules: { 
    email: {
     required:true,
     email:true,
     emailRule: true,
    },
    emailPass: {
     required:true,   
    },
   }, 
   messages: { 
    email: {
     required:"",
     email:"invalid email",
    },
    emailPass:{
     required:"",
    },
   },
   invalidHandler: function (ev, validator) {
       $('.row').find('label[for=email]').css({"color": "red"});
     },     
  });